# force biblatex (biber) to use english even \usepackage[french]{babel} is used

Tags: biblatex, babel, biber

My biblio.bib file is:

```
@article{D-V,
    author = {David, Wu and Vitas, Vang},
    title = {XXX.},
    journal = {YYY},
    year = {2006},
    volume = {12},
%%%
    number={1},
    pages={78--102},
},

@inproceedings{Liu,
    author={Feng, Liu},
    title={ZZZ.},
    booktitle={WWW},
    year={1973},
%%%
    volume={6},
    number={4},
    pages={553--603},
}
```

My .tex file is ( I used `\usepackage[french]{babel}`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     %% format d'encodage
\usepackage[french]{babel}      %% typographie française

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\bibliography{biblio} % or
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
This is an example of \cite{D-V}.
This is an example of \cite{Liu}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

You can see that, in the first entry, it shows `Wu David et Vang...`.
In the second entry, it shows `...T.6.4. 1973`

`et` in French is `and` in English. And `T.` in French (here) is `Vol.` in English.

If I remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[french]{babel}` in my .tex file, the output is

[image]

My goal is to keep `\usepackage[french]{babel}` for most part of my writing, but I want to keep the bibliography in English.

I tried to use `language={English}` and `hyphenation={English}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have changed the examples to use German instead of French to illustrate a point below.

You can load `biblatex` with the `language` option and specify `english`. By default this option is set to `autobib` and changes the language according to the `langid` field of the entry (what is changed in this case is controlled via the `autolang` option).

So `\usepackage[backend=biber,language=english]{biblatex}` gives an English bibliography (but with French title)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,language=british]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
This is an example of \cite[6]{sigfridsson}.
This is an example of \cite{nussbaum,aristotle:rhetoric}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can wrap the `\printbibliography` in an `otherlanguage`, but then you will have to load `english` as secondary language with `babel`. In the following example, the document is in German, but the bibliography in British English.

```
\documentclass[british,ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{babel}    

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
This is an example of \cite[6]{sigfridsson}.
This is an example of \cite{nussbaum,aristotle:rhetoric}.

\begin{otherlanguage}{british}
\printbibliography
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You will notice that the approaches show subtle differences: With the first, the language of the citations is also English ("p. 6"), while with the second it is German ("S. 6"). Then again, the first approach does not change the heading, while the second does. (Though that could be easily fixed.)